# Pass a list of values with keys into a column in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to pass a list of values with keys into a column

So it will look like this in the attributes

| Name | ID | Activity | Labels | Attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WholeFoods | 1 | grocery | ['Sam' , ‘Mark' , ‘...’] | [((’count_of_visits’,5) , (‘total_money_spent’,1500)) , ‘...’] |
| InstaCart | 2 | online shopping | ['John' , ‘James' , ‘...’] | [((’count_of_visits’,5) , (‘total_money_spent’,1500)) , ‘...’] |

I already grouped the labels into the same column, I was wondering how the attributes part could be done

```
SELECT
    s.name AS name,
    array_agg( s.client) as labels


FROM shopping_db s
GROUP BY  name
```

I tried passing values through this method but it didn't work

```
   SELECT
        s.name AS name,
        array_agg( s.client) as labels
    (VALUES (('count_of_visits', count(s.visits), 'total_money_spent',sum(s.amount))) AS attributes
    
    FROM shopping_db s
    GROUP BY  name
```

Comment: what does this structure mean `[((’count_of_visits’,5) , (‘total_money_spent’,1500))....]`

Comment: Kind of like list of list in array format here Attributes[1] will be corresponding to the labels[1]

Comment: Unrelated but this is a horrible data design. How do you sustain data consistency or even query such a structure? Go for a normalized one and you have all powerful tools on your belt.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using json

```
 SELECT
        s.name AS name,
        array_agg( s.client) as labels,      
        ARRAY[ json_object_agg('count_of_visits',count(s.visits)),
               json_object_agg('total_money_spent',sum(s.amount))
             ] AS attributes
    FROM shopping_db s
    GROUP BY  name
```